# Help getting the Flash player working on second screen?

Tags: video, xorg, nvidia, flash

I have a dual screen setup. I have a notebook LCD and a 17" monitor plugged into the VGA port on the notebook.

I have a GeForce 8400M GS video card with the NVidia 195.36.24 kernel module installed. I also have Compiz installed and enabled.

Here is the problem: when I try to view a webpage that uses the Flash player, the control is empty. For controls that play sound, I can actually hear the sound, but I can't see anything.

It works fine on the primary (LCD) monitor.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit.

Comment: Does the open-source nvidia driver work on your system? You can try this out with the 'xserver-xorg-video-nouveau' package.

Comment: @Jeremy: Could this really be the problem? And will the open-source driver provide all of the same capabilities?

Comment: I'd suggest it as a (potential!) easy fix. The nouveau driver is getting better all the time; for 2D stuff it should be on-par with the nv driver (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Drivers for details). Since it's using more of the standard kernel framework, I'd guess that this dual-monitor problem wouldn't occur. However, I'm no Xorg hacker, so I could be completely wrong! :)

Comment: @Jeremy: Don't forget I use Compiz :)

Comment: it still has 2d acceleration, so might be good enough for compiz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run nvidia-settings and make sure that you are using Twin-View rather than Xinerama or a "Separate X screen". If that doesn't solve your problem, check and see if disabling flash hardware acceleration solves the problem (keep in mind that flash has little to no benefit from linux hw-accel as of this post).